# One to Many Relationship NoForeignKeysError

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Having trouble creating a one to many relationship for a user with multiple profiles.
Here are my models:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column('id', db.String(32), primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column('email', db.String(45))
    password = db.Column('password', db.String(45))
    profiles = db.relationship('Profile', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

class Profile(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'profiles'
    id = db.Column('id', db.String(32), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column('user_id', db.String(32), db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    first_name = db.Column('first_name', db.String(45))
    last_name = db.Column('last_name', db.String(45))
    dob = db.Column('dob', db.String(45))
    sex = db.Column('sex', db.String(45))
    height = db.Column('height', db.String(45))
    weight = db.Column('weight', db.String(45))
    zip_code = db.Column('zip_code', db.String(45))
    date_created = db.Column('date_created', db.String(45))
```

I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.profiles - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

I have scoured the web and cannot figure out how I have it set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `users.id` instead of `user.id` because the table name is "users".

```
user_id = db.Column('user_id', db.String(32), db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```